# How can I use the same NERDTree buffer for directory listings and the sidebar?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When opening a directory in vim, NERDTree starts up with a directory listing. Later, toggling the NERDTree with `:NERDTreeToggle` opens a sidebar with a directory listing in a *different* buffer.

Because there are two instances of NERDTree — each running in its own buffer — changes, such as expanding or contracting nodes, are not in sync between them.

How can I prevent NERDTree from using different buffers entirely?

To illustrate:

[image: Different buffers]

Comment: Why do you open a second listing if you already have one?

Comment: It's not that I necessarily open the second one once the first listing is there, but rather that I'll use the first listing to open a file and later open the sidebar. The sidebar will have none of the changes I made in the first listing.

Comment: @JamieSchembri I can see the problem. But this is probably better suited as a feature request/bug on the plugin's issue tracker. -- that is, I can see that the NERD tree opens many NERD tree instances even though it shouldn't with `:NERDTreeToggle`.

Comment: @glts You're right, this seems like a bug to me. There's nothing in the help pages to indicate that it can be resolved with anything other than code changes, and it's not behaviour I'd expect. I've created a [new issue](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/289), but I'm leaving the question here — I believe it is solvable with the right function.

Comment: Your issue is not stated clearly and you conflate two unrelated issues. Basically, how you presented your problem actively hides the problem. Anyway, you are like the third or fourth person to complain here and elsewhere in the last week or so about NERDTree's inability to maintain state between two invocations and the solution is the same: ask the author to add that feature.

Comment: @romainl I don't see that there are two issues: I just need NERDTree to not use more than one buffer. I've attempted to clarify in my recent edit. The reason I asked here was because I presumed such an old plugin would have what is, to me, logical behaviour in this regard, and that I was simply missing something. In fact, NERDTree does maintain state when used with `:NERDTreeToggle`, only it does not apply to the invocation when opening a directory (`:e dir`).

Comment: Now the question is more clear. You should probably use the buitin `:Ex` and friends.